# Evaluation of a limite

Tags: limits

How to evaluate the following limit

$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \beta \, t^\alpha \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{(-a\,t^\alpha)^k}{\Gamma(\alpha\,k+\alpha+1)}
$$
with $\alpha\in]0,\,1[$, $a>0$ and $\beta\in\Bbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please be clear so we can help you where you need.

Comment: I considered that $1/\Gamma(\alpha\,k+\alpha+1)\leq 1/\min \Gamma(\alpha\,k+\alpha+1) $ to have a geometric series with a common ratio $r=-at^\alpha$, then I tried to use the Closed-form formula of the sum.

Comment: For the real numbers use `\Bbb{R}` , not `\Re`. For set removal, use `\backslash` or `\setminus`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be expressed in terms of the Mittag–Leffler function as follows:
$$
\beta t^\alpha  E_{\alpha ,\alpha  + 1} ( - at^\alpha  ).
$$
Using the known asymptotics of the Mittag–Leffler function along the negative axis (see, e.g., http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/10652469.2017.1399373) yields
$$
\beta t^\alpha  E_{\alpha ,\alpha  + 1} ( - at^\alpha  ) = \frac{\beta }{a} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{t^\alpha  }}} \right), \;\;\; t\to+\infty.
$$
Thus the limit as $t\to+\infty$ is $\beta/a$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and clear response! Also thanks for the valuable refrence.